# animation in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I'm very new to Jquery and I d'like to know why my function is not working. I am working on an 'Santa' animation. His body and one arm are separated from each other. The intention of this animation is that the single arm waves one time. Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Naamloos document</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="redbtn"></div>

<div id="santa_body">
    <div id="santa_arm"><img src="onderdelen/hand.png" /></div>
    <div id="santa_corpse"><img src="onderdelen/kerstman.png" /></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
#redbtn{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#F00;
    float:left;
    margin-top:30px;
}

#santa_body{
height:100px;
width:100px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
z-index:3;



}

#santa_arm{
margin-top: 100px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 0;
margin-left: 330px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: left top;
width: 400px;
height:200px;
z-index:1;
float:left;
}

#santa_corpse{
z-index: 2; 
width:500px;
height:600px;
position:absolute;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
float:right;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
 $("#redbtn").click(
     function(){
               $("#santa_arm").animate({
                 path : new $.path.arc({
                       center : [200,200],
                       radius : 150,
                       start : 0,
                       end     : -360 * 40,
                       dir : -1
                   })
            },40000);
    });
```

Comment: First off - I dont see jQuery JS file linked on your HTML page ...

Comment: Any im guessing your using this -> http://motyar.blogspot.com/2010/08/jquery-animate-in-circular-path.html again not linked ?

Comment: What errors do you get when this runs ? anything in a debugger ? javascript console ? anything ? (sorry for the multiple comments)

Comment: so I have to put the Jquery code in an external .js file? And yes, I'm trying that code you have there.I don't get any errors...

Comment: nope you dont need to put your code in an external js file ... to use jquery you must include the jQuery library js file in your page .. and to use the plugin (the page i linked to above) you must also link to an additional library file ... see here -> http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery

Comment: I see, fixed that, but it is still not working.

Comment: so please update the code above in your question ... or even better create a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/b77DH/1/  like this one?

Answer (score 0):

didn't get your question properly, but still try to inspect your page using firebug in firefox as the comments above already says, to identify the problem, and mention the actual error msg that appears(if any). 
PS :try after moving your "$("#redbtn").click()" function inside the $(document).ready(); block. (just saying, as you are new, :P)

Comment: I said that too soon, when I click on the red button (#redbtn) firebug gives me the error: $.path is undefined
[Afbreken op deze fout] path : new $.path.arc({

Comment: activate firebug, reload your page and confirm through the "Net" tab if you are missing to link any .js files(404 not found).

Comment: about each .js file i have imported, it says: status: 304 Not Modified.

Comment: if that's the case, then all the files that you are linking are getting loaded properly, **which means that**, you are definitely missing out on some external file, **the file that adds** the function called "path" to the base jQuery object. Can you provide the link to the reference url that you got this code from? Also the current copy of your html file(with all the js and css files properly linked) that you are working on.